# Eclipse plugin - creating a new class

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to write an eclipse plugin to auotmatically generate a java class from a text file. How can I do this in JDT?

The name of the class will be derived from the name of the text file, and I will want to generate some methods based on the contents of the text file.

I can probably do this the hard way, just writing to a file, but it seems like the JDT is the best way to go about this.